# simple text formatting inside of boxes issues

Tags: css

I have been fiddling with text within boxes for some time and i notice when the screen resizes the top of the box always adds this additional padding even if it is not in the code. is there any tip that would allow the box dimensions to not add extra padding when the screen resize?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create three columns of equal width */
.columns {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* Style the list */
.price {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Add shadows on hover */
.price:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

/* Pricing header */
.price .header {
    background-color: #111;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

/* List items */
.price li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Grey list item */
.price .grey {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* The "Sign Up" button */
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
}

/* Change the width of the three columns to 100% 
(to stack horizontally on small screens) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .columns {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
Try it Yourself »
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Basic</li>
    <li class="grey">$ 9.99 / year</li>
    <li>10GB Storage</li>
    <li>10 Emails</li>
    <li>10 Domains</li>
    <li>1GB Bandwidth</li>
    <li class="grey"><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="color:#ddd;background-color:#282E34;text-align:center;padding:20px 20px;text-align: justify;">
    <H2 ALIGN="CENTER">PLAN IT</H2><BR>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu </p>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI I believe the 'align' attribute has been deprecated since HTML5 - you may wish to consider using CSS to centrally align the `H2` element.

Comment: i had modified my example to show the padding being added. resize the page and you will see

Answer (score 0):

1st This is what you want? I don't see any padding added to your title after resize.

2nd try to not use inline style, create a class and put your style in it.

3rd `padding: 20px 20px;`(20px top/down, 20px left/right) is equal to `padding: 20px;` (20px for all 4 side)

4th create a class to center things since `align="center"` deprecated in HTML5:

ref: https://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html

```
.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mystyle {
  color: #ddd;
  background-color: #282E34;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div class="mystyle">
    <H2 class="centered">PLAN IT</H2>
    <BR>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsu </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what do you mean? Maybe It's because that I am using Chrome, so I can't see what you see. So the following answer is entirely based on imagination. Sorry about that

You can use F12 to see if the styling is actually a default styling which can be added by your browser.

To fix it, you can either introduce [**Reset CSS**](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) or [**normalize.css**](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to your pages, but put them in front of every other css file.

Or just simply stipulate `div {padding:0;margin:0;}` in the **very beginning** of your css

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using External CSS File

1. Create `yourname.css`

> ```
>  <head>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/external/stylesheet.css" />
> </head>
> ```

2. Add `<div id="yourpad" </div>` in your code
3. now simplly edit yourame.css and place this code

> .yourpad{ padding 0px 0px 0px}